# Passing a python list to a flask view is not working

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a very simple flask form setup with 1 field.  This field is passed via a POST Request to a script that runs and returns a render_template to the results page passing 4 list objects from the script.

I can run the script in the python interpreter and print the values of the lists.  But, it doesn't seem to be passing the lists back to the view.  I keep getting a form undefined error.  I think it is just skipping down to the return function in the index route instead of returning the view from the function.  Do I need to do something to the list variables before sending to the view?

**Route**

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = Search()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name=request.form['name']
        smoothSearch(name)
    return render_template("index.html", form=form)
```

**Function**

```
#function runs a for loop appending items to each list item then returns a render_template shown below
else:
    return render_template("results.html", usernames=usernames, userHandle=userHandle, userText=userText, postTime=postTime)
```

**EDIT to include jinja2 trackback below**

> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError
>   jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined
>
> Traceback (most recent call last)
>   File "/home/user/temp/code-projects/smoothSearch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in **call**
>   return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
>
> File "/home/user/temp/code-projects/smoothSearch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
>   response = self.handle_exception(e)
>
> File "/home/user/temp/code-projects/smoothSearch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
>   reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>
> File "/home/user/temp/code-projects/smoothSearch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
>   raise value
>
> File "/home/user/temp/code-projects/smoothSearch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
>   response = self.full_dispatch_request()
>
> File "/home/user/temp/code-projects/smoothSearch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
>   rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
>
> File "/home/user/temp/code-projects/smoothSearch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
>   reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>
> File "/home/user/temp/code-projects/smoothSearch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
>   raise value
>
> File "/home/user/temp/code-projects/smoothSearch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
>   rv = self.dispatch_request()
>
> File "/home/user/temp/code-projects/smoothSearch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
>   return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint
>
> File "/home/user/temp/code-projects/smoothSearch/app.py", line 22, in index
>   smoothSearch(name)
>
> File "/home/user/temp/code-projects/smoothSearch/smoothSearch.py", line 31, in smoothSearch
>   return render_template('results.html', usernames=usernames, userHandle=userHandle, userText=userText, postTime=postTime)
>
> File "/home/user/temp/code-projects/smoothSearch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 134, in render_template
>   context, ctx.app)
>
> File "/home/user/temp/code-projects/smoothSearch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 116, in _render
>   rv = template.render(context)
>
> File "/home/user/temp/code-projects/smoothSearch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
>   return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
>
> File "/home/user/temp/code-projects/smoothSearch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
>   reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>
> File "/home/user/temp/code-projects/smoothSearch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
>   raise value.with_traceback(tb)
>
> File "/home/user/temp/code-projects/smoothSearch/templates/results.html", line 1, in top-level template code
>   {% extends "index.html" %}
>
> File "/home/user/temp/code-projects/smoothSearch/templates/index.html", line 17, in top-level template code
>   {{ form.csrf_token }}
>
> File "/home/user/temp/code-projects/smoothSearch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 430, in getattr
>   return getattr(obj, attribute)
>
> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Assuming your **Function** is the end of `smoothSearch(...)`, you need a return statement in front of your function call.</s>

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = Search()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name=request.form['name']
        return smoothSearch(name)
    return render_template("index.html", form=form)
```

**Edit after question update:**

From your traceback you can see that on line 17 of `index.html` there is a call to `form.csrf_token`. Since you aren't passing a `form` to your template, it is throwing your error. Removing that from your `index.html` will solve this error but it will most likely break any forms you have. You'll have to go add the `form.csrf_token` back into all your forms.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I get the same jinja2 UndefinedError saying form is missing.

Comment: Can you confirm the `return render_template("results.html"...` is being reached? Also can you post the traceback and jinja2 template?

Comment: I have posted the trackback as an edit to the post.  No, I can't confirm that the render_template is being reached.  Could this be a timeout issue?  Maybe the script is taking too long to finish and exits to the index.html route?

Comment: I ended up just removing the {% extends index.html %} so that it wasn't passing it through.  Thank you so much for your help!